# Joomla sftp support

Tags: webserver, sftp, upload, joomla

I have a server which is shared and I don't have too much control on it. I was able to install Joomla 2.5, but whenever I upload any file, such as a template, the file owner (www) is different than my username, so that I cannot later ssh into the server and edit the uploaded files, which I need to do to change the logo, etc. I believe this is because the upload is through php.

I tried setting Joomla use ftp, but unfortunately ftp port is disabled and only sftp is available. Is it possible that I set Joomla somehow to use sftp for file upload and not ftp or php?

I am using Joomla 2.5 on a linux server.

**Edit**:
We finally solved this using [ACL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list). The webserver and my username were placed in the same group and we were both given write access to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the GROUP assigned to uploaded files? It is common for the owner to be the web server "user" but the group is generally something that will include your shell user id. You would still have this problem with FTP but then your server would be wide open to abuse.

If you are in the group, just make sure that the uploaded files are getting the correct permissions when uploaded.

Joomla will, indeed, be using PHP to upload because the uploaded files are local to itself, it doesn't need or want to use SFTP or any other remote mechanism. It's been a while since I used Joomla but I think that if you go to:

```
Site -> Global Configuration -> Server tab
```

In Joomla admin, you should be able to change the default permissions for file uploads.

Comment: No, I am not a member of the group, and I am not sure if I can convince the server admin to add me to the group. Moreover, the file permissions doesn't have the group write access anyway. 

But I don't think I will have problem with FTP or SFTP, since I can have Joomla use my shell username to upload files. I already have Wordpress on the same server which fortunately can use SFTP to upload. I was rather surprised to see Joomla doesn't have such option. In the "Server tab" there is only settings for FTP.

Comment: But if you do that, then Joomla won't have access will it? Then you wont be able to see the files in Joomla! Something is amiss. You're shell login must have access to the Joomla files otherwise you cannot maintain them from the shell?

Comment: If Joomla had SFTP option, I would have set it with my own username/password so that it would have access to my files. I currently do this for my Wordpress website.